# Is there a way to bring the icons in upper tray closer?

Tags: icons

[image: upper tray icons]
I was wondering if there was any way to bring the upper tray icons more closer so that they look appealing. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Ayatana indicators for apps , tlp, tlp UI , slimbook battery - works on DELL not only Slimbooks. It should work on all laptops.

Copy all bolded text below:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart && cp /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop ~/.config/autostart/ && sed -i 's/^OnlyShowIn.*/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;/' ~/.config/autostart/indicator-application.desktop && wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb && systemctl reboot
```

then type in terminal

```
cd /home/yourusername


sudo vi indicators.sh
```

press ins button to go into insert mode

press ctrl+shift+v to paste

press esc button to escape insert mode

type

```
:wq
```

this will write and quit the file

then type

```
sudo chmod +x indicators.sh
```

then type

```
./indicators.sh
```

script will run, install ayatana and restart the machine

Works in hera 5.1

For double wi-fi icon

```
mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop.old
```

Additional gift for battery saver. Requires tlp to work

```
sudo apt update



sudo apt install tlp



sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook



sudo apt update



sudo apt install slimbookbattery



sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

If you need also tlp UI

then type in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps



sudo apt install tlpui
```

---

to remove slimbook battery and app indicator

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove slimbookbattery gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

to remove tlp

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove tlp
```

to remove tlp UI:

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove tlpui
```

---

How to remove gaps between icons in wing panel a tutorial

1 - Install the wingpanel indicator mentioned in previous post

2 - Download libayatana_compatibility.so.zip from here: [libayatana_compatibility.so.zip](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/files/3776351/libayatana_compatibility.so.zip) and unzip it

Open terminal and go to Downloads

cd /home/username/Downloads

unzip libayatana_compatibility.so.zip

3 - Go To (with sudo) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

sudo -i

Type your sudo user password

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

4 - Backup your libayatana_compatibility.so

mv libayatana_compatibility.so libayatana_compatibility.backup

5 - Replace the libayatana_compatibility.so with the zipped one

cp /home/username/Downloads/libayatana-compatibility.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

6 - reboot

systemctl reboot

source

https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1

this works to me with no problem.